# ElasticSearch Mapping Non Searchable Field

Tags: php, python, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

Im new to elastic search.

In my `users` type in `profiles` index i have fields

```
properties : {
    name : {type : string},
    picture : {
                  url_small : {}
                  url_big : {}   
         } 
}
```

In this index `picture` is just for *storing/getting* data and will **never** be used in doing any query but only will be retrieved with matched hits.

So how to create the mapping of `picture` ? What `type`,`analyzer`,fields should i use ?

Comment: Hi Edward, use `index: no` and the type you want (`string` if 2.x, `text` if 5.x)

Comment: the picture is an *array of strings* making the picture {type : "string"} will do ?

Comment: Yes, you use the same mapping for string and array of strings (as long as it's not an associative array)

Comment: yes it is an assoc array its like `["picture"=>["url_small"="www.exe.com.jpg","url_big"=>"www.exs.com.jpg"] ]` @Pandawan

Comment: See answer below, my comment on array was because I thought you had `["picture"=>["url_small"=["url1", "url2"], ...`, in which case the mapping described below still work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Concepts:

You are dealing with two things here:

1. How the data will be stored
2. How the data will be indexed

To define how the data will be stored, you use `type`.

To define how the data will be indexed (directly, after being analyzed, or, in your case, not indexed), you use `index`.

And if you want to define how the data is analyzed for the indexing, you have to use `analyzer`.

#### In your case:

You want to store string, but not to index them, so you use:

```
{
    type: string,
    index: no
}
```

Which gives you:

```
properties : {
    name : {"type": "string"},
    picture : {
        url_small : {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
        },
        url_big : {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
        }   
    } 
}
```

#### More info on the index field here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/mapping-index.html

Hope it's clear

Comment: it's `"index": "false"` now for the current ES version (7.13)